# ElasticSearch not respecting custom mapping while indexing data

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am using ElasticSearch 6.2.4. Currently learning it and writing code in Python. Following is my code. No matter I give `age` as `Integer` or `text`, it still accepts it.

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}])
# index settings
settings = {
    "settings": {
        "number_of_shards": 1,
        "number_of_replicas": 0
    },
    "mappings": {
        "members": {
            "dynamic": "strict",
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "age": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
            }
        }
    }
}

if not es.indices.exists('family'):
    es.indices.create(index='family', ignore=400, body=settings)
    print('Created Index')

data = {'name': 'Maaz', 'age': "4"}
result = es.index(index='family', id=2, doc_type='members', body=data)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give `42` and `"42"` as numeric type just because it still numbers and it has no impact on searching and storing this field, but you can't give, for example, `"42a"` in any numeric field.

Comment: Brilliant. Did not think of it that it'd parse it as a numeric value anyway.